# Dificuldade em localizar valor em vetor em C

Tags: c

boa noite..
vou ser direto..

1. Sou estudante de ADS e estou no segundo semestre..
2. preciso desenvolver um sistema de estacionamento rotativo.
   Nisso o usuario precisa inserir a placa do veiculo e devemos atribuir a isso se o mesmo é idoso, pne ou padrão, e também o horario de entrada do veiculo no estacionamento.
   Porem não estou conseguindo fazer nem a primeira parte do exercicio que seria cadastrar uma placa e depois encontrar ela no vetor onde ela foi cadastrada.

Segue abaixo o código e peço q me ajudem a encontrar onde estou errando.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char placa[5];
int op;

void cadastro ();
void pesquisaPlaca ();

int main () {
    
cadastro ();
pesquisaPlaca ();

return 0;
}

void cadastro (){
do {
    char placa1;
    printf ("\ndigite a placa do veiculo:");
    scanf ("%s",&placa[placa1]);
    printf ("digite 1 para novo cadastro ou 0 para sair:");
    scanf ("%d",&op);
    placa1++;
} while (op==1);
    
}

void pesquisaPlaca (){
    char placaPesq;
    int j;
    
    printf ("\ninsira a placa a ser pesquisada:");
    scanf ("%s",&placaPesq);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    for (j=0;j<=placa;j++) {
        if (strcmp(placa[j], placaPesq)) {
            printf ("\nplaca %s encontrada.", placa[j]); // nao localiza a placa
        } else {
            printf ("\nplaca nao encontrada");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note que aqui: `char placa1; printf ("\ndigite a placa do veiculo:"); scanf ("%s",&placa[placa1]);` você declara `placa1` mas não atribui nenhum valor à variável. Ao utilizar em `placa[placa1]` a variável `placa1` conterá lixo de memória.

Answer (score 0):

Algumas dicas:

Aqui você só guarda uma placa de tamanho de 5 caracteres;

```
char placa[5];
```

Você precisa de um vetor de placas que contenha o numero das placas, sugestão:

```
#define TAMANHO_PLACA 5
#define MAXIMO 10

char placas[MAXIMO][TAMANHO_PLACA];
```

No cadastro você precisa seguir a mesma ideia e usar o tamanho da placa

```
int i = 0;
do{
    char tmp[TAMANHO_PLACA];
    printf ("\ndigite a placa do veiculo:");
    scanf ("%s",tmp);
    strcpy(&placas[i][0], tmp);
    i++;
}while(opt != 0 || i == MAXIMO);
```

para pesquisar, basta percorrer o vetor de placas comparando com a que deseja:

```
char tmp[TAMANHO_PLACA];
printf ("\ndigite a placa do veiculo:");
scanf ("%s",tmp);
for(int i = 0; i <= MAXIMO; i++)
{
    if (strstr(placas[i], tmp) != NULL)
        printf ("achou:");
   
}
```